# Как оформить следующий случай?

Tags: пунктуация

Иногда говорят: «Не надо внедрять, что мол, то, что хорошо, и само освоится».

Мой вариант: Иногда говорят, что «не надо внедрять», что мол «то, что хорошо, и само освоится».

Answer (score 3):

Мол – выделяем запятыми. И никаких кавычек после МОЛ – это косвенная речь.

Иногда говорят: не надо ничего внедрять. Что хорошо, то, мол, и само освоится.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Иногда говорят, что не надо внедрять, а то, что хорошо, и само освоится.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ:

1) Частица МОЛ говорит о том, что перед нами чужая речь, чужое мнение, но здесь уже есть такое указание (оформление сообщения в виде косвенной речи).

2) Нет особой необходимости в точности передачи речи, так как используются стандартные формулировки. При наличии большого желания можно применить такой вариант: Иногда говорят, что не надо внедрять, а "то, что хорошо, и само освоится".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Если без МОЛ нельзя обойтись (требуется ирония), то можно предложить следующий вариант:
Иногда говорят, что, мол,  не надо внедрять, а то, что хорошо, и само освоится.

Comment: Не надо внедрять (ЧТО)? Ничего. Явно же не хватает дополнения. Разговорная фраза стала неряшливо-разговорной.

Comment: Я редактирую представленный материал, стараясь максимально сохранить исходное содержание, при этом контекст отсутствует. Со всеми вопросами о "неряшливой разговорности" просьба обращаться к автору вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Попробовали бы мы так вольно переписать какого-нибудь классика! Давайте максимально приблизимся к оригиналу:

Иногда говорят: "Не надо внедрять", мол, то, что хорошо, и само освоится.

Иногда говорят: "Не надо внедрять" (мол, то, что хорошо, и само освоится).

Иногда говорят: "Не надо внедрять", что, мол, хорошее и само освоится [убрала повтор "что"].

Иногда говорят: "Не надо внедрять" - что, мол, хорошее и само освоится [авторское тире вместо запятой].

Comment: Стиль речи важен. У классиков свои художественные задачи, а в данном тексте множество запятых и скобок только затемняет смысл. М какую функцию здесь выполняет слово "мол", если косвенная речь уже обозначена?

Comment: По-моему, это предложение не нуждается в переделке, потому что максимально точно передает живую речь и последовательность образов, всплывающих в сознании говорящего. Если бы я хотела донести данный смысл, то сказала бы точно так же, как написано. Иногда говорят: "Не надо внедрять!" (передаем интонацию чужой речи: громко, категорично, можно с восклицанием). Дальше передаем косвенно, вставляя МОЛ: подчеркиваем условность суждения, свое несогласие с ним, словно язык не поворачивается продолжать дальше от первого лица, хочется добавить иронии.

Answer (score 2):

Кавычки здесь действительно не нужны.

Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях: 
1) нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка:
Про Ивашку говорили: крепкий (А.Т.). Дома и хворать легче и жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: дома и стены помогают (Ч.).

То же, если высказывание говорящего передается приблизительно (тем самым утрачивая характер прямой речи): Предлагаемый проект, указал докладчик, получил уже апробацию на практике.
Справочник-практикум. Стр.305. Д.Э. Розенталь.

Answer (score 1):

Убрать не нужное **что** и фраза "заиграет". **Мол** - это вводное слово (оно выделяется запятыми), предваряющее пояснение автора всего предложения позицию противников внедрения.